# How to write a class method to dispose an existing form in c#

Tags: c#

I have two forms in my project, form1 and form2. I have added a new class to my project. It has a method which accepts a form object and it should be able to do following things.

1. show the accepted form object (frm.ShowDialog())
2. When I press enterkey on the displayed form (frm) it should close. (without adding code to form2 s keydown event). it should be handled by the newly added class.

I tried to add new keyeventhandler but I don't know how to proceed from here. (Dispose() doesnt work)Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

```
class Class1
{
    public static void SearchResultBox(Form2 frm) 
    {            
        frm.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(frm_KeyDown);
        frm.ShowDialog();

    }

    static void frm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {


        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the form passed in and then use that reference to close the form

```
class Class1 
{   
    private static Form2 _frm = null;  
    public static void SearchResultBox(Form2 frm)      
    {                     
         _frm = frm;
         frm.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(frm_KeyDown);         
         frm.ShowDialog();      
    }      
    static void frm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)     
    {         
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)         
        {     
             if(_frm != null)
             {      
                 _frm.Close();
                 _frm.Dispose();
             }
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u steve. this gave me an error. "Warning 1 Field 'WindowsFormsApplication15.Class1._frm' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null"

Comment: Answer updated. I assume that this will avoid the error, but can't test now.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't frm.close(), and frm.dispose() perform the task you're asking for.

```
static void frm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
    {
        frm.close();
        frm.dispose();

    }
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: thank you Hmm. frm.close() and frm.dispose() dont work because I in a different method in the class.

Comment: @chaarr - What do you mean it does work?  If you are sending the reference to the form, then it should work, provided you are invoking the method of course.

Answer (score 0):

create your own `Form` class and use [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), like this

```
public class MyOwnForm : Form 
{
    private override OnLoad(...)
    {
        base.OnLoad(..);

        AcceptButton = yourOkButtonObject;
    }
}
```

where `yourOkButtonObject` is the object of the "OK" buton that I **suppose** present on your form. If not any other button that *confirms* the form.

Comment: you set AcceptButton of the form to the button you wna to be "clicked" on ENTER button press in *your* form type. After use your form type along your program. So *all* forms in your application will close on ENTER button press